# Incorrect syntax for SELECT TOP with a Parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, sqlparameter

I used to have this one

```
Dt = MyMod.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP " & QuestionsPerCats(i) & " * From Questions WHERE CategoriesID ='" & Cats(i) & "' ORDER BY NEWID()")
```

but now i decided to use sqlparameters like

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP @QuestionsPerCats * From Questions WHERE CategoriesID = @CategoriesID ORDER BY NEWID()", conn)
Dim sqlParam As SqlParameter = Nothing
sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionsPerCats", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
sqlParam.Value = QuestionsPerCats(i)
sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoriesID", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
sqlParam.Value = Cats(i)
```

which unfortunately "renders" like

```
SELECT TOP @QuestionsPerCats * From Questions WHERE CategoriesID = @CategoriesID ORDER BY NEWID()
```

and returns the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near '@QuestionsPerCats'.
```

So what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You might try using cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP (@QuestionsPerCats) *
FROM Questions
WHERE CategoriesID = @CategoriesID
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

[(SQL Server 2005 and up)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520123828/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: Just a little more info: SQL 2005 made a change to the TOP keyword so that it is now a function that can take a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Include @QuestionsPerCats in (), as defined in [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3532226/TOP-Clause-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm) link

```
SELECT TOP (@QuestionsPerCats) * 
From Questions 
WHERE CategoriesID = @CategoriesID ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: With over 800 rep you probably should have figured out `code tags` by now, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionsPerCats", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
cmd.Parameters("@QuestionsPerCats").Value = QuestionsPerCats(i)


cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoriesID", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
cmd.Parameters("@CategoriesID").Value = Cats(i)
```

The method you are using to add parameters to the command is a little weird.  I suspect this may be the cause of your error.

Comment: @downvoter, is the method he used normal in VB.NET?  I am a C# guy, so please correct me if I am wrong.